# Using find on non-integer MATLAB array values

Tags: matlab, floating-point, comparison

I've got a huge array of values, all or which are much smaller than 1, so using a round up/down function is useless. Is there anyway I can use/make the 'find' function on these non-integer values?

e.g.

```
ind=find(x,9.5201e-007)
```

FWIW all the values are in acceding sequential order in the array.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you're using isn't correct.

```
find(X,k)
```

returns `k` non-zero values, which is why `k` must be an integer.  You want

```
find(x==9.5021e-007);
%#   ______________<-- logical index: ones where condition is true, else zeros
%#   the single-argument of find returns all non-zero elements, which happens
%#   at the locations of your value of interest.
```

Note that this needs to be an exact representation of the floating point number, otherwise it will fail.  If you need tolerance, try the following example:

```
tol = 1e-9; %# or some other value
val = 9.5021e-007;
find(abs(x-val)<tol);
```

Comment: Excellent, I had tried the `find(x==9.5021e-007);` first but forgot the `==` (haven't been on my game today I guess...) I need one exact value so this works w/o tolerance. Thanks!

Comment: @tmpearce: for the last one: `find( abs(x-val)<tol )`

Answer (score 0):

When I want to find real numbers in some range of tolerance, I usually round them all to that level of toleranace and then do my finding, sorting, whatever.

If `x` is my real numbers, I do something like

```
xr = 0.01 * round(x/0.01);
```

then xr are all multiples of .01, i.e., rounded to the nearest .01.  I can then do

```
t = find(xr=9.22)
```

and then `x(t)` will be every value of `x` between 9.2144444444449 and 9.225.

Comment: This would work I but I have so much data and I need an accurate index of the exact number I'm looking at. So I have no tolerance area.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from your comments what you want is

```
`[b,m,n] = unique(x,'first');
```

then `b` will be a sorted version of the elements in x with no repeats, and

```
x = b(n);
```

So if there are 4 '1's in `n`, it means the value `b(1)` shows up in `x` 4 times, and its locations in `x` are at `find(n==1)`.